# Consensual or Non-Consensual sex with Female slaves in Islam

Tags: slavery, consent

اسلام عليكم
I was reading about slavery in islam. The matter which striked my mind is Why a slave women will give consent for sex to her master who owns her because we know that she became slave due some circumstances(captured in war) not by her own will.

Comment: I think this is part of the answer of https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/649/13438 so your question should already be covered on the site.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answerable question, even if asked of any human being who consents to sex beyond "I want to" and that's about it. Could you offer any other clarification? However, [Stockholm syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_syndrome) is worth mentioning, where a captive becomes attracted to or otherwise allies with the captor, which could lead to consenting sex of a twisted type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Muslim men allowed to take "sex slaves?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Islamic scholar, but from what I learnt/researched.... here are my findings. 
As far as I know, since the idea of prison or dungeons weren't really favoured for war criminals or prisoners in Islam. They were placed in houses as slaves or servent....atleast that's better than rotten in a cell. Anyways, slaves in Islam are meant to be treated with the utmost kindness and leniency. As it may occur, sometimes, female/male slaves living with familes may develop desires etc. In such cases "I THINK"....is why sex with slaves has been permitted. Please do correct me if I am wrong! So if a female slave gives consent...then it should be fine. But if she doesn't then it should be respected...SO HER CONCENT IS HER WILL. 
And this is my understanding!
Jazakallah

Answer (score -6):

It is against the rulings of the Quran to enslave the male or female war captives and to have sexual relations with them without marriage. Although the verses about this subject are clear, by distorting the meanings of words, a false perception was created and it has been turned into the common view of all sects including Sunni and Shia female captives can be used as concubines. For full explanation & details please visit https://www.islamandquran.org/common-mistakes/battle-captives-and-concubinage.html

Comment: A long article with wrong statements (interpretations) is this a kind of advertisement for your site? Be aware that the qur'an certainly confirms slavery, else why should we expiate by freeing slaves! It wouldn't make sense. Sadly people who know they are wrong don't give others the option to comment on their sites! As they don't accept oposite views.

Comment: Please visit the site for details.

Comment: I've visited the site. You say you have a method, but a wrong method may lead to anything as a prinicipal rule of logic says: ex falso quottlibed.