# What is the link between mentioning oprhans and the permission for polygyny in (4:3)?

Tags: tafseer, polygamy, surat-an-nisa, orphans

Why does the famous and well known verse about polygyny starts by referring to orphans:

> And if you fear that you will not deal justly with the orphan girls, then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. But if you fear that you will not be just, then [marry only] one or those your right hand possesses. That is more suitable that you may not incline [to injustice]. ([4:3](https://legacy.quran.com/4/3))

There must certainly be a reason why Allah started the verse referring to orphans. 
Does anybody can explain it?

Comment: Isn't this the same as [What's the link between being unjust to orphan girls and having up to four wives in verse (4:3)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49968/) ?

Comment: @UmH thanks the alternatives provided by the system were not suggesting this one. Else I wouldn't have asked the question. On the other hand maybe the answers there could use some elaboration.