# When is polygamy permitted?

Tags: sunnah, polygamy

What are the conditions for polygamy to be permissible according to Quran and Sunnah?

Is there any hadith that allows marrying non-orphans?

Comment: Read [Polygyny in Islam](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/14022)

Comment: Sorry, but what is the relation between polygamy and marrying non-orphans? There's no restriction on whom one can marry... See also [What's the link between being unjust to orphan girls and having up to 4 wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49968/whats-the-link-between-being-unjust-to-orphan-girls-and-having-up-to-four-wives). The topic of conditions for marrying more than one wife are already covered on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Polygamy is a type of relationship that typically involves a male marrying more than one female. It is permissible in Islam; as Allah states in **[4:3]**

> If you fear that you might not treat the orphans justly, then marry the women that seem good to you: two, or three, or four. If you fear that you will not be able to treat them justly, then marry (only) one, or marry from among those whom your right hands possess.6 This will make it more likely that you will avoid injustice.

---

### Condition of Polygamy:

**1)Justice or Fairness**

> “but if you fear that you shall not be able to deal justly (with
> them), then only one.” [al-Nisa 4:3]

This verse indicates that just treatment is a condition for plural marriage to be permitted.

If a man is afraid that he will not be able to treat his wives justly if he marries more than one, *then it is forbidden for him to marry more than one.*

What is meant by the justice that is required in order for a man to be permitted to have more than one wife is that he should treat his wives equally in terms of spending, clothing, spending the night with them and other material things that are under his control.

With regard to justice or fairness in terms of love, he is not held accountable for that, and that is not required of him because he has no control over that. This is what is meant by the verse,

> “You will never be able to do perfect justice between wives even if it
> is your ardent desire.” [al-Nisa 4:129]

**2)The Ability to Spend on one’s Wives**

The evidence for this condition is the verse:

> “And let those who find not the financial means for marriage keep
> themselves chaste, until Allah enriches them of His Bounty.” [al-Nur
> 24:33]

In this verse, Allah commands those who are able to get married but cannot find the financial means, to remain chaste. One such example is not having enough money to pay the mahr (dowry) and not being able to spend on one’s wife.

---

Thank you to [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en) for references/help.

Answer (score 1):

One sufficient condition: Being able financially and physically to fulfill wives needs with an intent to be fair between them.

I.E. not being unjust.. just like any other thing you might do, you have to be fair.

> Is there any hadith that allows marrying non-orphans?

Polygamy is way common in Seerah (Biography of the Prophet), Prophet (SAW) and nearly all of the Sahaba have married more than one woman (that are non-orphns) at the same time.. (Personally, I'd sometimes consider Polygamy is Sunnah, but this is not the case in Islam.. Polygamy is permissible if the condition above is fulfilled).

Polygamy in many situations is reformative doing and Muslim who do this is likely to be rewarded Insha'Allah.

Almighty Allah Knowing.

---

Credits to [this post](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/109879/%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%A9) (Arabic) and [this one](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/7844/%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%A8%D8%A3%D9%83%D8%AB%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%A9) .

Comment: I would recommend adding [4:3](https://quran.com/an-nisa/3)

Comment: Thank you bro, I didn't mention the verse to avoid a common argument that usually happene about the interpretation.. Just prefer to mention the Fatwa and what the Ummah is agreed on.